# How to use Azure Disks in more than one VM

Tags: azure, architecture, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I am trying to use a disk called "relAI_results" in two VM: NeurologycaTest & kernel.

NeurologycaTest is a Windows 10 VM, and Kernel an Ubuntu one.

In the next image you can see I achieved to put relAI_results as a data disk of the Windows VM.

[image]

But the problem is when I try to put it in the Ubuntu one, here you can see there is no option of it, the disk is an SSD standard one.

[image]

Any ideas mates? Thanks

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Answer (score 0):

¡I found the answer!

In the configuration of the disk there is an option to mark in which maximum devices you want to share the disk, first the disk it has to be disconnected.

[image]

¡Thanks anyway community!